# Filtering rows on DataFrame based on data in a Series

Tags: python, pandas

There's a DataFrame `df` containing following data:

```
+------+----------+-------+
| YEAR | CATEGORY | GRADE |
+------+----------+-------+
| 1999 |     A    |  3.5  |
| 1999 |     A    |  7.2  |
| 1999 |     B    |  0.2  |
| 1999 |     B    |  6.4  |
| 2000 |     A    |  1.4  |
| 2000 |     A    |  2.5  |
| 2000 |     B    |  3.3  |
| 2000 |     B    |  8.4  |
+------+----------+-------+
```

And there's a multi-indexed Series `s` containing passing scores:

```
YEAR  CATEGORY 
1999  A         5.2
      B         5.1
2000  A         3.7
      B         6.1
dtype: float64
```

So I would like to filter rows on `df` that `GRADE` is greater than value on `s` in a fashion that the result is like the following:

```
+------+----------+-------+
| YEAR | CATEGORY | GRADE |
+------+----------+-------+
| 1999 |     A    |  7.2  |
| 1999 |     B    |  6.4  |
| 2000 |     B    |  8.4  |
+------+----------+-------+
```

How can I proceed to obtain this result?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set_index` and using `gt` with boolean to filter the df

```
yourdf=df[df.set_index(['YEAR','CATEGORY']).GRADE.gt(s).values]
yourdf
   YEAR CATEGORY  GRADE
1  1999        A    7.2
3  1999        B    6.4
7  2000        B    8.4
```