# Filtering rows on DataFrame based on data in a Series failing with DataFrame range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I asked some days ago the question that was wonderfully answered here: [Filtering rows on DataFrame based on data in a Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253291/filtering-rows-on-dataframe-based-on-data-in-a-series)

This works very well with the original DataFrame:

```
yourdf=df[df.set_index(['YEAR','CATEGORY']).GRADE.gt(s).values]
yourdf

   YEAR CATEGORY  GRADE
1  1999        A    7.2
3  1999        B    6.4
7  2000        B    8.4
```

But if I get just some rows like the following, I get this error:

```
df = df[2:]
yourdf=df[df.set_index(['YEAR','CATEGORY']).GRADE.gt(s).values]

ValueError: Item wrong length 7 instead of 6.
```

How can I do that with a subset of the DataFrame?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix with `reindex`

```
df=df.set_index(['YEAR','CATEGORY'])
yourdf=df[df.GRADE.gt(s.reindex(df.index)).values]
yourdf
Out[250]: 
               GRADE
YEAR CATEGORY       
2000 B           8.4
```